# Como fazer um repositório GIT voltar a ser uma pasta comum do sistema?

Tags: git, github, versionamento

Boa noite, estou aprendendo GIT. No início eu criei como repositório a pasta da minha área de trabalho. Que contém diversos arquivos que não tem nada haver com meus projetos. Então, gostaria de saber se tem como desfazer isso, não quero apagar a pasta minha área de trabalho. Só quero que ela volte a ser uma pasta comum do sistema e não um repositório GIT. Como faço isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando você roda o comando `git init` um novo repositório é criado. Isso nada mais é do que a criação de uma pasta **oculta** chamada `.git`. Todas as informações relativas ao git estão contidas nesse diretório.

Na sua área de trabalho existe essa pasta. Se você a deletar, esse diretório deixará de ser considerado um repositório Git. Se você não a consegue ver, é porque seu sistema operacional está com a configuração de esconder arquivos e pastas ocultos. Você pode desmarcar essa configuração e deletar manualmente.

Uma [outra opção](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3212465/10746978) é abrir o prompt de comando do Windows ou o Terminal do Linux/Mac na área de trabalho e deletar essa pasta por lá.

Para referência, no Mac/Linux o comando seria o seguinte:

```
rm -rf .git
```

Para mais informações sobre como visualizar arquivos ocultos ou um passo a passo mais detalhado, veja [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1213446/10746978) (em inglês).

Answer (score -1):

```
git restore --source=HEAD --staged --worktree -- aDirectory
# or, shorter
git restore -s@ -SW  -- aDirectory
```

Com o Git 2.23 (agosto de 2019), você tem o novo comando "[git restore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48508799/how-to-reset-all-files-from-working-directory-but-not-from-staging-area/57066072#57066072)"

Isso substituiria o índice e a árvore de trabalho pelo conteúdo `HEAD`

Observe que:

```
git checkout -- <path>
```

não faz uma reinicialização completa: substitui o conteúdo da árvore de trabalho pelo conteúdo preparado.

```
git checkout HEAD -- <path>
```

faz uma redefinição definitiva para um caminho, substituindo o índice e a árvore de trabalho pela versão do commit `HEAD`.

Se você tiver arquivos extras na árvore de trabalho que não existem no HEAD, um `git checkout HEAD -- <path>` não os removerá.

Nota: Com o git checkout `--overlay HEAD -- <path>` (Git 2.22, Q1 2019), os arquivos que aparecem no índice e na árvore de trabalho, mas não em `<tree-ish>` são removidos, para fazer com que correspondam exatamente a `<tree-ish>`.